# UIToolbar missing in QLPreviewController modal view

Tags: iphone, ios, toolbar, qlpreviewcontroller

I've created a modal QLPreviewController with view of a PDF doc:

```
[self presentModalViewController:preview animated:YES];
```

However it's missing a UIToolbar at the base of the controller's view.
I had thought of supplying the toolbar myself; but I would have to wait till the PDF is loaded before adding to the base within the controller's view.  There must be a simpler/standard way to provide a toolbar.

Is there a simple way to supply a toolbar that I can use to navigate from this modal QLPreviewController?

Comment: Qlpreviewcontroller has very limited customization options.  Maybe only bar buttons if I remember correctly.  Maybe a UIView that houses your toolbar that could be presented on top of the modal view.

Comment: I eventually added the qlpreviewcontroller to an existing UINavigationBar.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably achieve this by nesting the preview controller inside a `UINavigationController`, and if necessary setting its `toolbarHidden` property to `NO`.

Then present the navigation controller.